# MongoError : Server 127.0.0.1:3000 timed out at null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting an error in cmd when i run "node app.js" command.

> "facebook-auth\express-authentication" is my path to NodeJS project.

[image]

I run my MongoDB and i think it is working fine.
[image: mongod command]

and

[image: mongo command]

When i use "node app.js" command in starting then my "http://127.0.0.1:3000" server work fine but when i close all connections and try to restart mongoDB then is error occur everytime.
I don't know how to solve this problem and this project is running fine in starting on http://127.0.0.1:3000. But don't know what happened know. I closed my MongoDB using Ctrl+C.

After adding this code

> // When successfully connected

`mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () { console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + dbURI); });`

> // If the connection throws an error

`mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) { console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err); });`

to app.js it shows this:
[image]

Showing an error and website authentication not work properly(But website is running now). It don't get callback information from localhost or 127.0.0.1. It keeps waiting for response for localhost and callback doesn't complete (stuck there).

> I follow this tutorial :[Here](http://www.danielgynn.com/build-an-authentication-app-using-express-node-passport/) and project is working fine.

"Is this a conflict between xampp or mongoDB or nodeJS"

App.js file linked [Here](http://pasted.co/82991f7a)

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: try this code to check connect made or not // When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + dbURI);
}); 

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});

Comment: @codeGig : I add this code to app.js and after that do i need to restart MongoDB again?

Comment: no, but you need to start your app again through node app.js

Comment: @codeGig: Nothing happened, showing same error.

Comment: Can you show me your app.js file

Answer (score 1):

> Waiting for connections on port **27017**.

Vs.

> Server 127.0.0.1:**3000** timed out.

Don't let me think everything is fine.

You either have to change the port, where app.js is connecting to, to Mongo's [standard port](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/) *27017*, or start `mongod` with `--port 3000` to listen on port 3000.

Comment: Change `var port` in your _app.js_ to 27017. 2nd hint: Let Mongo listen on Port 3000. It depends on your goal. Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and this is what I got each time I run my app.

```
/home/sarojs/projects/ror/liveProject/bq-ng/brandqast- ng/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                  ^
MongoError: server 127.0.0.1:8080 timed out
at null.<anonymous> (/home/sarojs/projects/ror/liveProject/bq-ng/brandqast-ng/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:436:40)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/sarojs/projects/ror/liveProject/bq-ng/brandqast-ng/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:144:10)
at g (events.js:260:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/sarojs/projects/ror/liveProject/bq-ng/brandqast-ng/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:172:12)
at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at TCP._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

I found that the mongoDB URI that I was setting was 8080 as port no.
I simply changed the port to 27017 as it is the default port. It worked perfectly fine.